# Sort strings by year,month and day

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python.

**Basic problem:
Extract a sorted list of file names by year, month and day from directory**

I'm writing a script that search for the latest bak

file in directory and importing it to database.

Files have the following format:

```
MyDB_05-09-2017.bak

MyDB_05-10-2017.bak
```

I wish to extract the most up to date bak file by the file name.

I want to sort the files by year,month and day.

**This is some basic implementation I have tried:**

```
import glob,os,re
from datetime import datetime

# SQL server backup directory
os.chdir('C:\\SQLServerBackups')

# invoke the sql script to drop the database if exists
os.system('C:\\SQLServerBackups\\database_sql_scripts\\drop_database.bat')

# find the latest .bak file and rename it to target

file_list = glob.glob('*.bak')
latest_bak_file = file_list[0]
latest_year = 0
latest_month = 0
latest_day = 0

for file in file_list:
    print(file)
    del_list = re.split('[-._]',file)
    temp_latest_year = int(del_list[3])
    temp_latest_month = int(del_list[1])
    temp_latest_day = int(del_list[2])

    if temp_latest_year > latest_year:
        latest_year = temp_latest_year
        latest_month = temp_latest_month
        latest_day = temp_latest_day
    elif temp_latest_year == latest_year:
        if temp_latest_month > latest_month:
            latest_month = temp_latest_month
            latest_day = temp_latest_day
        elif temp_latest_month == latest_month:
            if temp_latest_day > latest_day:
                latest_day = temp_latest_day
                latest_bak_file = file

print(latest_bak_file)
```

Any advice on how can I implement it better?

I wish to have a sorted list of file names by year,month and day.

Comment: Oh dear, but there's a built-in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function

Comment: As is said I'm really new to python and I have tried to see if I can use that function but I can't seem to figure out how to use it in this situation. 
I'll look into this function again and see how to implement it better...

Comment: Use datetime: `datetime.strptime('MyDB_05-09-2017.bak', 'MyDB_%d-%m-%Y.bak')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define a sort key function that returns the fields you want to sort by:

```
import re

fnames = [
    "MyDB_05-10-2017.bak",
    "MyDB_05-09-2017.bak",
]

def sortkey(x):
    parts = re.split('[-._]', x)
    return [int(parts[3]), int(parts[1]), int(parts[2])]

sorted_fnames = sorted(fnames, key=sortkey)
```

or, as @Klaus D said, use `datetime.strptime` in your search key:

```
sorted_fnames = sorted(fnames, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, 'MyDB_%d-%m-%Y.bak'))
```

Comment: Yea, that can do the trick nicely! thanks! 
I'll try to implement it and see if it works.